# How to limit a PHP script so that it only works if it GETs an image from the local server?

Tags: php, image

I have a dynamic resizing image script that gets the location of the image to be resized-on-the-fly from a GET variable.

How can I limit the script so that it ONLY works if a local image is passed?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the format of your GET parameter?  Is it a URL, path or something else?

Comment: It can be any format.  Right now, anything from 'http://' (external site) to '../' (local) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the file exists on your hard disk:

```
if (file_exists($myImageDir . '/' . $_GET["image_url"])) processImage();
```

*Don't forget to cleanup any GET or POST vars before using in your code.*